# Banach's Fixed Point theorem extra condition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

My question doesn't concern Banach's fixed point directly but rather an extra condition that I have seen pop up at different times, but I can't remember where.

Let $T:X\rightarrow X$ be the contraction from Banach's fixed point theorem where we assume $X$ is also a normed space with the norm ||.||.

Then the extra condition for $f\in X$:$||Tf||\leq||f||$ is often shown.

Of course if one verifies this condition one obtains that $T$ indeed maps $X$ into $X$, however if we already know this what does this condition ensure?

I'm asking from a differential equations viewpoint. If I remember correctly this condition helped with achieving a continuation of a solution in time, i.e. rule out blow-ups.

I am sorry if this question is vague, but I was just wandering what I had previously used this condition for?

Comment: That’s just because, typically, $T(0)=0$.

Comment: I don't quite understand, what does this condition ensure in this case?

Comment: Right, that’s not the end of the story. The complete answer is that, typically, $X$ is a ball in a Banach space and $T(0)=0$. So, that condition ensures that $T$ is a well-defined mapping of $X$ into itself.

Comment: That makes sense, so in this case it is just used to show that subspaces are also mapped into subspaces which isn't a priori known from the fact that $T$ maps $X$ into $X$.

Comment: Why does $X$, which is only a nonempty complete metric space and need not have any relation with any normed space in the statement of the contraction mapping theorem, have a norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$?

Comment: Oh sorry that is just an extra assumption I added, I'll clarify it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is probably motivated by a typical application of the contraction mapping principle to PDEs. Now I am going to just make up a toy model, to illustrate the **main points** of this argument; these points are marked by blackboard font. The answer to the question lies in the last point.

---

Consider the initial value problem
$$\tag{1}
\begin{cases} 
\partial_t u = \Delta u +u^2, & t\in (0, T), x\in \mathbb R^n, \\
u(0, x)=u_0(x).
\end{cases}
$$
We want to establish that, if $T$ is sufficiently small, then there is a solution $u\in C(0, T; L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n))$. This is the Banach space of functions $u=u(t,x)$ that are bounded in $x$ for all $t\in (0, T)$, and such that the map
$$
t\in (0, T)\mapsto u(t, \cdot)\in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$$
is continuous.

This is not the only evolution space, but it certainly is the most natural; we can afford $u(t, x)$ to be defined for almost all $x$, but we must require it to be defined for all $t$, for the initial condition $u(0, x)=u_0$ to make sense. Thus, a space such as $L^p(0, T; L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n))$ is not good, because its elements are defined only for almost all $t$. This is why we chose a space of continuous functions of $t$. With this argument, **we have chosen the ambient Banach space**.

Now we need to choose the candidate contraction mapping. Here, the input comes from the classical theory of ODEs; we define
$$
\Phi_{u_0}(u) = e^{t\Delta}u_0 +\int_0^t e^{(t-s)\Delta}(u^2(s, \cdot))\,ds,$$
because, if $v(t, x)$ is an arbitrary function, then $\Phi_{u_0}(v)$ solves the initial value problem
$$
\begin{cases} 
\partial_t u = \Delta u + v^2, \\ 
u(0, x)=u_0(x).
\end{cases}
$$
**We have given a formal definition of our candidate contraction mapping**.

To finish the setup of the functional framework, we need one more input. We gave a formal definition of $\Phi_{u_0}$, we established that it must be defined in some closed subset $X$ of the Banach space $E:=C(0, T;L^\infty)$, but we still haven’t specified such subset. To do so, we observe that, since $\lVert e^{t\Delta}f\rVert_\infty\le \lVert f\rVert_\infty$, then
$$\tag{2}
\lVert \Phi_{u_0}(u)\rVert_E \le \lVert u_0\rVert_\infty + T\lVert u\rVert_E^2.$$
And this suggests the definition of $X$. We let
$$
X=\{v\in E\ :\ \lVert v\rVert_E\le R\}.$$

I can now, finally, answer the question. Why is this a good choice for $X$? First, it is a complete metric space. Second, by (2) we see that
$$
\lVert\Phi_{u_0}(u)\rVert_E \le \lVert u_0\rVert_\infty +TR^2,\quad \forall u\in X, $$
thus if $R=2\lVert u_0\rVert_\infty$, then for all
$$
T\le \frac{1}{4\lVert u_0\rVert_\infty}, $$
we have that $\Phi_{u_0}$ maps $X$ into $X$. Notice that what we did with (2) is exactly what the question asks; controlling
$$
\lVert \Phi_{u_0}(u)\rVert_E \text{ in terms of }\lVert u\rVert_E.$$
**We have found the correct domain for the mapping $\Phi_{u_0}$**.

We are not done. We still need to prove that $\Phi_{u_0}$ is a contraction mapping. I am not going to do so; it may be that this requires taking a smaller $T$. If somebody is interested then they should look into some book in parabolic PDEs, such as the one of Quittner and Souplet, which is the one I used to write this answer. (P. Quittner, P. Souplet, “Superlinear parabolic problems”, Theorem 15.2, https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764384425).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer :)

Comment: @Annie: It is a pleasure, I am glad it helped. I made a couple edits.